# Shortcut for "run application" in Unity

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook

What is the keyboard shortcut for run application in unity, or how do I get to the applications screen quickly?

I've still got the gnome application for setting keyboard shortcuts, and it has <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>f2</kbd> set for "Show the run command prompt", but that doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report about this ("Unity needs a run dialog").

Comment: With `Super` I can see small numbers on the side bar and I can use it with `Super + 1-0`, obviously it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @skalka: thanks. I knew about that and I have been trying to use it more (and it is handy) but every now and then I just need a run dialog anyway.

Comment: Bonus advice: once you narrowed the application entry down to your desired application in first place: **pressing 3x <tab>, followed by 3x ↓, followed by enter** allows you to reach the item to start in a mouse-less fashion :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install [gmrun](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gmrun)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gmrun
   ```
2. Use the **Add** button in **gnome-keybinding-properties** to create a new action with the command **gmrun**. You can then bound it to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or any other combination.

This however is not as powerful as the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> of the gnome-panel.

---

Other alternatives:

Install [kupfer](http://packages.ubuntu.com/kupfer)

```
sudo apt-get install kupfer
```

Install [gnome-do](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gnome-do)

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

Install [Synapse](http://packages.ubuntu.com/synapse)

```
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

Comment: I think Gnome-Do is a very good replacement of "Run Application".

Comment: I tried out both, not sure which I'll pick eventually but gnome-do is less heavy than I thought it would be, so sticking to that for now.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/580295

Comment: https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/580295/comments/9 - SABDFL says it's on the list for Natty

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
[Five alternative apps for ALT+F2 functionality in Unity](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/omg-5-five-ways-to-add-altf2-fun-to-unity/)